# dplyr: average over a range based on first occurrence in a different column

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use dyplr and mutate to create a new variable that is either 0 or the average the values in column y, conditional on a range from column z.

For column z range, I would like to use the first time z >= 90 for the max value of the range and then the first time z=31 immediately before z >= 90 for the minimum value of the range.

Note: I will be grouping by column x

For example:

```
x  y   z 
1  100  0 
1  90   0 
1  90  31 
1  90  60 
1  80  31 
1  75  60 
1  60  90
1  60  60
2  60   0
2  60  30
```

I would to average y over this range:

```
  x  y   z
  1  80  31
  1  75  60
  1  60  90
```

so I would end up with the value 71.7 (I don't care about rounding).

```
x  y   z  ave
1  100  0    0
1  90   0    0
1  90  31    0
1  90  60    0
1  80  31 71.7
1  75  60 71.7
1  60  90 71.7
1  60  60    0 
2  60   0    0
2  60  30    0
```

Comment: But wouldn't `1 75 60` be the first time z>=31 immediately before first z>=90?

Comment: Julius Vainora: The condition is greater than or equal to 31, not greater than.

Comment: Yes. But then if we go from `1 60 90` up, it's `1 75 60` that satisfies the condition first. If we go from the top, it's `1 90 31`. So why skip `1 75 60` (assuming that we need to go up)?

Comment: Ah, got you. I made a mistake, = 31, not >=31. Will fix. Thank you.

Comment: Would this happen multiple times in a dataset (for a given `x`)? e.g. two instances of z=31, ..., 90 ?

Comment: Yes, Z can move to 90 (or above) multiple times. so for any given x, they could have a z = 0, 31, 60, 90, 120, 90, 60, 90, 60, 31, 60, 90, 120, .... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do

```
df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(ave = {
  if(any(z >= 90)) {
    idxU <- which.max(z >= 90)
    idxL <- max(which(z[1:idxU] == 31))
    replace(z * 0, idxL:idxU, mean(z[idxL:idxU]))
  } else {
    0
  }
})
#    x   y  z      ave
# 1  1 100  0  0.00000
# 2  1  90  0  0.00000
# 3  1  90 31  0.00000
# 4  1  90 60  0.00000
# 5  1  80 31 60.33333
# 6  1  75 60 60.33333
# 7  1  60 90 60.33333
# 8  1  60 60  0.00000
# 9  2  60  0  0.00000
# 10 2  60 30  0.00000
```

So, `idxU` is the upper limit for the range, `idxL` is the lower limit, then in the last line we replace elements `idxL:idxU` of the zero vector `z * 0` by the required mean.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start, but yes, tons of errors when no 31 or 90+

Comment: @Travis, ah, ok, wasn't sure whether that's possible. Will update the answer soon. So, 1) no 31 & no 90+ implies 0 everywhere, 2) 31 exists but no 90+ implies what? Starting from somewhere and going till the end? And analogously with no 31 and with 90+.

Comment: The data is for days past due (delinquent accounts). for your points: 1) Correct. 2), 31 exist, 90+ doesnt, then 0. 3) if 90 exists, 31 will definitely exist.

Comment: @Travis, see the update. If 90+ exists, then the code is the same, otherwise 0.